# jquery data tag and GET

Tags: jquery

I have the jquery below that changes the visibility of a div depending on a button being clicked, what I would like to do now is have a data tag from the button be used as a variable that I can run with PHP, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

```
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("button").click(function () {
        var Swapper = $(this).attr("href")
        /* var model = $(this).data("model_id") How can I use the model variable?*/
        var $swap = $(Swapper).stop(true, true),
            visible = $swap.is(':visible');
        $swap.slideToggle("fast");
        if (visible) {
            $(".ContentSwap.defaultSwap").show();
        } else {
            $(".ContentSwap:visible").not(Swapper).hide();

        }

    });

});
```

PHP generated Button

```
echo "<button type='button' id=equipment_swap' class='Add' data='model_id=".$equipment_model_id."' href='#editEquipmentSwap'>Edit</button>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this to echo the button (You did it wrong):

```
echo "<button type='button' id=equipment_swap' class='Add' data-model_id='".$equipment_model_id."' href='#editEquipmentSwap'>Edit</button>";
```

In `jQuery` you may try this:

```
var model = $(this).attr("data-model_id");
```

So the `model` variable will get the value from `data-model_id`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this

PHP

```
echo "<button type='button' id=equipment_swap' class='Add' data-model_id='".$equipment_model_id."' href='#editEquipmentSwap'>Edit</button>";
```

jQuery

```
var model = $(this).data("model_id");
```